# IN Flutter Web getting 'XMLHttpRequest' error while making HTTP call

Tags: php, flutter, flutter-web

I am using XAMPP control panel and using a local server like Apache port no 80, but in flutter web getting XMLHttpRequest error and in mobile device. The same coding fetches data using API not getting any error.
How to fetch data using API while app run on flutter-web?

Error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Syncing files to device Chrome...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56619/FsXy3a4ZrZg=
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56619/FsXy3a4ZrZg=
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1450:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 143:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 696:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 725:32                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 519:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1302:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37312:58                              <fn>
    
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:5555/dart_sdk.js:4361:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:5555/dart_sdk.js:38189:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:5555/dart_sdk.js:38183:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:5555/dart_sdk.js:38015:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:5555/dart_sdk.js:38021:13)
    at http://localhost:5555/dart_sdk.js:33518:9
```

Backend Side PHP Webservice

```
<?php

header("Access-Control_Allow_Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

include 'config.php';

$sql="select * from calinsert";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die("query failed");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
    $output=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($output);
}
else{   
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>'no record found','status'=>false));
}
?>
```

Flutter Side Code

```
Future getdata()async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'http://localhost:80/web_service/calview.php',
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control_Allow_Origin": "*"
        });

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: I have the same Problem do you have a solution?

Answer (score 10):

In most cases of Flutter API use, add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value in header might resolve the issue. (Note: This will help in access the local or external APIs)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Hint: you have typo in your above header, please check and correct.

Comment: This is most likely the problem as many others with this error solved it by adding CORS to their request header.  I didn't catch the type as you did.

Comment: Where in my file do I have to to put the code?

Comment: @Berl its header part, where you define `Content-type`

Answer (score 4):

Just removed the header attribute from the post method and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, But I need to send headers with my post request!!!!

Answer (score 3):

1. Fix the typo (replace underscores by dashes):

   ```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   ```
2. Add the following header in your php code:

   ```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept");
   ```

Comment: 2 nd point not understood can you share some examples? i m use laravel for api.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently getting this error as well and I seem to have fixed by upgrading my package to the most recent `0.12.2` version and it seems to have helped - so far.

https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: @DarpitPatel - have you checked the browser console to see if there is any more specific errors that might help identify the root cause?  https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/433

Comment: Is this issue only for web app or also getting issue for mobile app deployment?

Comment: @JubinPatel yes it's only on flutter web app

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simply it is CORS error.
you have to  add "localhost:XXXX" or the corresponding address to the CORS origins in the backend code to get it run in debug mode.
Eg: in FastAPI,
[CORS Management in FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message and tried all to config the CORS policies right and it was working from the browser with a simple Javascript fetch but not with Flutter Web http.

Long story short, it fails becausee of my self signed certificate.

As it turned out the badCertificateCallback i was using for Flutter mobile is not working with Flutter web.

Maybe that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
F12 Tools -> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44360/xxyy' from origin 'http://localhost:52273' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

More info - CORS is usually a sever side issue, you have to set up what clients are allowed.  For development purposes, my flutter web is talking to a .net core service so I had to enable CORS in development mode only to allow CORS using the following:

```
builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.AccessControlAllowHeaders, "Content-Type")
                .AllowAnyMethod();

        }));
```

Comment: what is the solution ?

Comment: I updated post with my service config using .net core.  Your service might be different.  Basically allow CORS for development.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose for me with my Appwrite server. I just had to add localhost as a trusted web app and it started working without issues.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

While I deployed flutter application apache xampp server i receive below error.

FrontEnd in Flutter (abc.com)
Backend in laravel (apiabc.com)

there a 2 domain

Answer (score 0):

you have to add "https://app.flutterflow.io" to your list of allowed origins from your app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).