# How to get SteamApp list in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the game list from the Steam API.
I know that in this link there is a page with all the games/apps in a JSON format: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/
The thing is that I don't know how to get that JSON inside the app. What I tried is downloading the whole website (html) and looking in the correct html tag for the string content that is the JSON, but I guess that there is a better way to get the content.
Also, doing that way I can only make it work in web, when I also want it to work in app version.

Any idea on how to get the content of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to launch a request to that API which will give you a response that you can store in a variable.

If the response is in JSON format and you want to treat it as such, you will have to decode it (basically transform from simple text to JSON)

To launch a request you can use Dart's http package which you can import like this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

You then make a call to a `get` method (or in other cases you would use a `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` ... method) by passing it the *API uri* using the `Uri.parse()` method.
Store the response in a variable.

```
final response = await http.get( Uri.parse('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/'));
```

Now the variable "**response**" will hold the output of what the server at the API you provided will return (amongst other information)

To get the content, you have to access `response.body`(other useful information inside of "**response**" will be `response.statusCode` that gives you as the name indicates the status of your response which can tell you about errors, successful requests...)

Finally tranform the content into *JSON* using the `json.decode()`

```
import 'dart:convert';//<-- you need to import to be able to use the function
final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body)
```

The overall code would look something like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final response = await http.get( Uri.parse('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/'));
final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body)
//Do whatever you want with jsonResponse
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. Very detailed and well explained. I have only one question. I'm trying to run the code, the thing is that I'm getting the next error running it on a browser: Error: XMLHttpRequest error. C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 910:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22

Comment: @Axvemi Might be related to CORS but you have no control over the API so not much you could do. Try to "_disable-web-security_" since I believe this won't be a production app. You'll find the steps here in the 3rd answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458696/in-flutter-web-getting-xmlhttprequest-error-while-making-http-call

Comment: Yeah, It's that. It works on android and desktop versions, the problem it's only on web so it should not be a problem since i'm not going to use that one. Thanks!